# Flutter causes Error: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dio

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static const nycLat = 40.7484445;
  static const nycLng = -73.9878531;
  static const apiKey = "My_Api_Key";
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container();
  }
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    print(await searchNearby('hospital'));
  }
  Future<List<String>> searchNearby (String keyword) async {
    var dio = Dio();
    var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters';
    var parameters = {
      'key' : apiKey,
      'location':'$nycLat,$nycLng',
      'radius' : '800',
      'keyword' : keyword,
   };
    var response = await dio.get(url, queryParameters:parameters);
    return response.data['results']
        .map<String>((result) => result['name'].toString())
        .toList();
  }
 }
```

Here is my code of searching nearby places list.
I followed exactly the same thing from this video = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtYLyWnW8f8
And what I only changed is the 'data:parameters' part in the end because it shows red underline error so I changed to 'queryParameters:parameters'. But the error 'Error: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: XMLHttpRequest error.' comes out.

```
 Running with sound null safety 
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56039/Y3tKhTSoDB8=/ws
Flutter Web Bootstrap: Auto
Error: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: XMLHttpRequest error.
Source stack:
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 963:28       get current
packages/dio/src/dio_mixin.dart 488:35                                                                                fetch
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54       runBody
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5       _async
packages/dio/src/dio_mixin.dart 487:31                                                                                fetch
packages/dio/src/dio_mixin.dart 483:12                                                                                request
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54       runBody
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5       _async
packages/dio/src/dio_mixin.dart 453:33                                                                                request
packages/dio/src/dio_mixin.dart 61:12                                                                                 get
packages/leftover/main.dart 41:29                                                                                     searchNearby
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54       runBody
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5       _async
packages/leftover/main.dart 32:37                                                                                     searchNearby
packages/leftover/main.dart 30:17                                                                                     didChangeDependencies$
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54       runBody
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5       _async
packages/leftover/main.dart 28:29                                                                                     didChangeDependencies
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4963:11                                                                   [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4781:5                                                                    mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3817:15                                                                   inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3551:18                                                                   updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1202:16                                                                     [_rebuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1171:5                                                                      mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1119:16                                                                     <fn>
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2597:19                                                                   buildScope
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1118:12                                                                     attachToRenderTree
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 952:24                                                                      attachRootWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 933:7                                                                       <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 48:19  internalCallback

    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:5080:11)
    at http://localhost:55923/packages/dio/src/interceptors/log.dart.lib.js:1043:21
    at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:40515:59)
    at _FutureListener.catchError.handleError (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:35449:33)
    at handleError (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:36015:51)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:36041:17)
    at [_completeError] (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:35878:23)
    at [_completeError] (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:35358:36)
    at _SyncCompleter.new.completeError (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:35282:29)
    at onError (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:35122:49)
    at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:40515:59)
    at _FutureListener.then.handleError (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:35449:33)
    at handleError (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:36015:51)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:36041:17)
    at [_completeError] (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:35878:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:35927:31)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
    at http://localhost:55923/dart_sdk.js:36261:9
```

And here is my error.
I searched for solutions but couldn't get any that actually can help me.
Could anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance